# Alternative to Tippecanoe for generating Mapbox vector tiles on command-line

Tags: vector-tiles, mbtiles, mapbox-gl-js, command-line

Tippecanoe is the tool I always use for converting Shapefiles/GeoJSONs to Mapbox vector tiles in PBF format, for rendering in Mapbox-GL-JS. But it doesn't seem ideal: its primary use case seems to be processing enormous point datasets such as tweets which means:

- It focuses on points, not lines or polygons.
- Many of its settings are focused on determining which features to drop.

There are other limitations in practice:

- its processing of line and polygon features can be really ugly,
- its "base zoom" model is not well explained, so that working through its dozens of configuration parameters is pretty hit and miss.
- although it has some per-feature properties like `maxzoom` and `minzoom` it doesn't have a way to vary which properties are included per level
- its functioning is pretty opaque, there's not much information generated about what choices were made at each level, how "heavy" the tiles are overall, etc.

So my question is: are there other ways to convert vector files to vector tiles that work better for polygons and lines?

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-tile-copy is an alternative. I believe that's the exact process that happens when you upload to Mapbox. For a bunch of reasons it's less user friendly than tippecanoe. And you still need to then bundle up your mvt into an mbtiles.

Comment: Also github.com/NYCPlanning/geojson2mvt outputs mvt static files using node. Very simple. Uses geojson-vt.

Comment: Huh, that's strange @AndrewHarvey - cutting vectors into tiles and uploading to S3 seem like pretty separate tasks. Wonder which bit does the actual vector tile generation.

Comment: Tilelive-omnivore or one of its dependencies maybe...

Comment: How do you store the data? Is PostGIS an option? I am using PostGIS to generate and store tiles in separate table to the table with the geometry.

Comment: I don't normally use PostGIS. That's a prettty massive dependency. What's the benefit it's providing you? @DennisBauszus

Comment: It provides us with the benefit of having two tables in one database. The feature table being editable by open source desktop such as QGIS. Maintenance wise this is preferred to a file based solution.

Comment: Oh, for maintaining geometries, cool. I don't do much of that - mostly I'm getting geometry and data from somewhere else, merging and processing, then generating vector tiles. I very rarely "own" any geometry.

Answer (score 4):

Tippecanoe is designed for lines and polygons as well.  Here's a recommended starting point for representing polygons at all zoom levels, with one property you want to aggregate at low (zoomed-out) levels when features are combined to keep tiles small and visually useful.

```
tippecanoe -o out.mbtiles -P --coalesce-smallest-as-needed --detect-shared-borders --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping -z12 --accumulate-attribute=my-attribute:sum|max|min|avg mydata.geojson
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the `--accumulate-attribute` flag before, interesting. (I'm definitely aware that Tippecanoe supports lines/polygons, but some of that support feels quite bolted on, and the default behaviour is often pretty terrible without a bunch of flags...)